# Como eu faço para passar parâmetros do último Fragment para o Fragment anterior?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Eu tenho a seguinte situação: abre-se o `Fragment A` e dele, com um evento de click no botão, vai para o `Fragment B`. Quando estiver no `Fragment B` e apertar o botão voltar, com o intuito de voltar para o `Fragment A`, gostaria de passar alguns parâmetros para o `Fragment A`. Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das maneiras de fazer isso é fazer com que as `Activities` conversem entre si e que os `Fragments` consigam comunicar-se com as `Activities` ou entre si por meio delas. Segue a descrição das duas porções que precisariam ser implementadas.

---

## Entre `Activities`

O cenário mais comum (que parece ser o seu) é quando uma atividade filha é iniciada para colher respostas do usuário - como escolher um ciontato de uma lista ou digitar um texto. Neste caso você deveria usar `startActivityForResult` para iniciar a sua atividade filha.

Isso provê um meio para enviar de volta dados para a atividade principal (pai) usando o método `setResult`. Este método usa um `int` como valor para o resultado e um `Intent` é passado de volta para a atividade que a chamou.

```
Intent resultado = new Intent();
// Adicione extras ou uma URI de dados para esta intent como apropriado.
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultado);
finish();
```

Para acessar os dados retornados pela atividade filha sobrescreva (faça um `override`) o método `onActivityResult`. O `requestCode` corresponde ao `int` passado na chamada  `startActivityForResult`, enquanto o `resultCode` e os dados do `Intent` são retornados pela atividade filha.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch(requestCode) {
    case (ATIVIDADE_FILHA) : {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // Extraia os dados retornados pela atividade filha.
      }
      break;
    } 
  }
}
```

---

## Entre `Fragments`

Para fazer os `Fragments` conversarem entre si você prececisa criar uma interface para isso e as `Activities` dos `Fragments` precisam implementar essa interface. Feito isso as `Activities` podem conversar entre si por meio da técnica demonstrada anteriormente.

No seu `Fragment` Pessoa você precisa criar a interface que será usada e chamar o callback nos eventos apropriados (á sua escolha).

```
public class PessoaFragment extends Fragment {
    OnSettingsListener mCallback;

    // A Activity que contém o fragment deve implementar esta interface
    public interface OnSettingsListener {
        public void OnSettingsDone(int data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        
        // Este código serve para nos certificarmos que a Activity que contém o Fragment
        // implementa a interface do callback. Se não, lança uma exceção
        try {
            mCallback = (OnSettingsListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " precisa implementar OnSettingsListener");
        }
    }
    
    ...
    
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Envia o evento para a Activity que chamou
        mCallback.OnSettingsDone(position);
    }
    
}
```

Na `Activity` mãe ou principal, que chamarei de `Main`, você precisa implementar a interface e fazer a comunicação adequada.

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements PessoaFragment.OnSettingsListener{
...

    public void OnSettingsDone(int position) {
        // O usuário selecionou uma posição da configuração

        PessoaFragment pessoaFrag = (PessoaFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pessoa_fragment);

        if (pessoaFrag != null) {
            // Se o fragment da pessoa está disponível, estamos num layout de dois painéis (num tablet)

            //Chama um método para atualziar o conteúdo
            pessoaFrag.atualizaConfiguracao(position);
        } else {
            // Se não, estamos num layout de um painel apenas e precisamos trocar os fragments...

            // Cria um fragment e passa para ele como parâmetro as configurações selecionadas
            PessoaFragment newFragment = new PessoaFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(PessoaFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
        
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Troca o que quer que tenha na view do fragment_container por este fragment,
            // e adiciona a transação novamente na pilha de navegação
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack("pilha");

            // Finaliza a transção com sucesso
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Certo. Fico grata pela resposta. Eu usava isso para trabalhar com `Activity`, porém acho que não é aplicável, dessa maneira, no uso de `Fragments` devido ao uso de transações consecutivas. Poderia me indicar disso ou de algo do tipo com transações nos `Fragments`?

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada. Como você está iniciando os Fragments no momento? Você deve ter uma `Activity` relacionada com cada `Fragment` ou pelo menos uma principal que gerencia todos `Fragments`, certo?

Comment: Sim tenho uma `Activity` que gerencia todos os `Fragments`. Vou colocar aqui o código.

Comment: `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


Fragment currentFragment = new PessoaFragment();


FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();


fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
replace(R.id.content_frame, currentFragment, "tagConfigPessoas");



fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("pilha");


fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Comment: @FerzinhaFil dá uma olhada na atualização que fiz comentando sobre a comunicação entre os Fragments.

Comment: Nossaa, obrigado @AlexandreMarcondes . Vou usar esta lógica na minha aplicação. Esclareceu muitas dúvidas minhas, obrigado de verdade. Parabéns pela disposição e pela explicação. Beijos. Obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Isso resolvi de um modo simples para algo simples.
Em uma activity Master onde gerência os Fragments eu declaro uma variável publica.

```
public class Master extends ActionBarActivity {

  public long idTeste;
```

E então nos Fragments é setada e obtida das seguintes maneiras

```
 Master master = (Master)getActivity();
 master.idTeste = 1;
 int id teste = master.idTeste;
```

Assim mantendo o valor da variável declarada na Master e navegando entre Fragments.

Outra maneira é criar uma classe com propriedades estáticas.

Agora, se as duas maneiras são boas práticas de se programar, eu não sei.