# Iniciando segunda atividade com resultado no Android

Tags: java, android

Tenho dois `editText` que entro com um in e um botão de calcular. Gostaria de apresentar o resultado em uma segunda atividade assim que pressionasse o botão calcula. Alguém poderia me ajudar nisto?

Comment: Você precisa fornecer mais detalhes em sua pergunta. O que você já fez? Qual código você já tem? Qual o ponto com maior dificuldade para entender?

Answer (score 2):

O modelo básico para passar informações entre Acitivities é esse, segundo a [**documentação do android**](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, OutraActivity.class);
  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.meuEditText);
  String message = editText.getText().toString();
  intent.putExtra("mensagem", message);
  startActivity(intent);
```

E para pegar na `OutraActivity.class`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra("mensagem");
```

Há mais exemplos na documentação, aproveite e dê uma conferida, está em inglês mas é bem ditático.

Referências para estudo:

http://www.ideiasprogramadas.com.br/android-passando-dados-telas/

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

[Como eu faço para passar parâmetros do último Fragment para o Fragment anterior?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11854/como-eu-fa%C3%A7o-para-passar-par%C3%A2metros-do-%C3%BAltimo-fragment-para-o-fragment-anterior)

[Passagem de parâmetros de uma Activity para outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12421/passagem-de-par%C3%A2metros-de-uma-activity-para-outra)